# i can't add info as an array in my class students

Tags: c#

i made a class of student which have a parameter courses and grades that are array but when i try to add a student it does not allow me enter details as in array i van only enter just one word or number

```
Student s1 = new Student(dev, 1691676, "eng,maths", 50 );
```

here is the code

```
  public class Student
  {
    public string name;
    public int studentId;
    public string[] courses;
    public int[] grades ;


    public Student(string name,int studentId,string[] courses,int[] grades)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.courses = courses;
        this.grades = grades;

    }
    public void info() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name of the student is" + name);
        Console.WriteLine("StudentID of the student is" + studentId);
        Console.WriteLine("courses taken by student are" + courses);
        Console.WriteLine("grades earned by the student are" + grades);

    }
    public void sleep() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter the amount of time the student slept");
        int sleep=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int a = grades.Length;
        int b = 0;
        if (b<a)
        {
            grades[b] = grades[b] - (sleep / 10);
        }       
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you probably want to read up about how arrays work. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot.its realy helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an *array*, `string[]`, not a single `string`; but you can either `Split` string into an array:

```
// As aquinas noticed, grades is an array as well as courses
Student s1 = new Student(dev, 1691676, "eng,maths".Split(','), new int[] {50} );
```

or provide the array as it's expected:

```
Student s1 = new Student(dev, 1691676, new string[] {"eng", "maths"}, new int[] {50} );
```

Comment: Grades is an array too of course, so you'll need new int[] { 50 }